# Code failing to split int -> short -> byte and viceversa using c#

Tags: c#

I have this function:

```
private void IncrementCommandCounter(int iCommandBank, bool bLowWord, bool bLowByte)
{
    // Split the Int32 into two short values
    short loWord = (short)_CommandCounters[iCommandBank];
    short hiWord = (short)(_CommandCounters[iCommandBank] >> 16);

    // Split the first short into two byte values
    byte loByte1 = (byte)loWord;
    byte hiByte1 = (byte)(loWord >> 8);

    // Split the second short into two byte values
    byte loByte2 = (byte)hiWord;
    byte hiByte2 = (byte)(hiWord >> 8);

    // Increment the appropriate counter
    if(bLowWord)
    {
        if (bLowByte)
            loByte1++;
        else
            hiByte1++;

        // Rebuild first short
        loWord = (short)((loByte1 << 8) | hiByte1);
    }
    else
    {
        if (bLowByte)
            loByte2++;
        else
            hiByte2++;

        // Rebuild second short
        hiWord = (short)((loByte2 << 8) | hiByte2);
    }

    // Combine the two shorts and return
    _CommandCounters[iCommandBank] = ((loWord << 16) | (hiWord & 0xffff));
}
```

And also this one:

```
private int GetCommandCounter(int iCommandBank, bool bLowWord, bool bLowByte)
{
    // Split the Int32 into two short values
    short loWord = (short)_CommandCounters[iCommandBank];
    short hiWord = (short)(_CommandCounters[iCommandBank] >> 16);

    // Split the first short into two byte values
    byte loByte1 = (byte)loWord;
    byte hiByte1 = (byte)(loWord >> 8);

    // Split the second short into two byte values
    byte loByte2 = (byte)hiWord;
    byte hiByte2 = (byte)(hiWord >> 8);

    // Increment the appropriate counter
    if (bLowWord)
    {
        if (bLowByte)
            return loByte1;
        else
            return hiByte1;
    }
    else
    {
        if (bLowByte)
            return loByte2;
        else
            return hiByte2;
    }
}
```

But they are not working correctly.  If I call:

```
IncrementCommandCounter(0, true, true);
IncrementCommandCounter(0, true, false);
IncrementCommandCounter(0, false, true);
IncrementCommandCounter(0, false, false);
```

Then call, eg:

```
ed.WriteMessage("Bank 2, Lo Word, Low Byte: " + GetCommandCounter(2, true, true).ToString());
ed.WriteMessage("Bank 2, Lo Word, High Byte: " + GetCommandCounter(2, true, false).ToString());
ed.WriteMessage("Bank 2, Hi Word, Low Byte: " + GetCommandCounter(2, false, true).ToString());
ed.WriteMessage("Bank 2, hi Word, High Byte: " + GetCommandCounter(2, false, false).ToString());
```

At the moment I get:

```
Bank 2, Lo Word, Low Byte: 4
Bank 2, Lo Word, High Byte: 0
Bank 2, Hi Word, Low Byte: 0
Bank 2, Hi Word, High Byte: 4
```

That is not right. The pairs of values should be systematically incrementing during my tests.

My mistake?

---

- The numbers are all positive. We are starting with 0.

Comment: ` (short)((loByte1 << 8) | hiByte1)` - did you swap hi and lo here?

Comment: Seems you're doing the same when rebuilding the final result, shifting the low word up.

Comment: @KlausGütter @ Lasse Thanks guys.